# ranking results of mysql query using AVG

Tags: mysql

I have a query that ranks results in MySQL:

```
SET @rank := 0;
SELECT Name, Score, @rank := @rank + 1 
FROM Results 
ORDER BY Score
```

This works fine until I try to base the ranking on the average score:

```
SET @rank := 0;
SELECT Name, AVG(Score) as AvScore, @rank := @rank + 1 
FROM Results 
ORDER BY AvScore
```

If I run this I get just the one record back because of the AVG. However, if I add a GROUP BY on Name so that I can get the averages listed for everyone, this has the effect of messing up the correct rankings.

I know the answer's probably staring me in the face but I can't quite get it. How can I output a ranking for each name based on their average result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a sub-query:

```
SET @rank := 0;

SELECT a.name, 
       a.avscore, 
       @rank := @rank + 1 
FROM   (SELECT name, 
               Avg(score) AS AvScore 
        FROM   results 
        GROUP  BY name) a
ORDER  BY a.avscore
```

Comment: Thanks, this has fitted perfectly!

Comment: How would I incorporate the variable set inside the query so that I don't have to run multiqueries in php?

Answer (score 1):

You have to order first and then select rank from a derived table:

```
SELECT Name, AvScore, @rank := @rank + 1
FROM (
    SELECT Name, AVG(AvScore) AS AvScore FROM Results 
    GROUP BY Name ORDER BY AVG(AvScore)
) t1, (SELECT @rank = 0) t2;
```

Comment: Take that back, I'm actually getting nulls? It's ordering fine, it just won't output the rank...?